# Enable all defined bash completion after a custom command

Tags: linux, bash, script, autocomplete, tab-completion

I have a custom script called `oEd` which basically runs any bash command following it and **o**pens the output in my favorite **Ed**itor.

Is it possible to enable all defined bash completion (supported by my bashrc) after this custom script?

For example: I would like to do.

```bsh
$ oEd man ls
$ oEd find .
```

Here, I have created `oEd` just it would be more useful if it supports all completions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want completions after `oEd` to behave like after `exec`. Let's copy this behavior. This is how you can find it:

```
complete -p exec
```

In my Ubuntu the output is `complete -F _command exec`. You need to invoke:

```
complete -F _command oEd
```

Comment: Thank you. One additional thing, is it possible to supply multiple completion functions? For example, in addition to showing the completion for `exec`, if I also want to include the completions for `ls` for `oEd`. So I tried this in bashrc `complete -F _command -F _fzf_path_completion oEd`, but it doesn't work? Could you please suggest changes? Also writing the two completions statements (with -F argument) separately, overwrites the previous completion statement.

Comment: @Nikhil In general I cannot easily merge two completions. You can force filename completion by triggering `complete-filename` whenever you need. I believe it's `M-/` (i.e. Alt+/) by default.

Comment: Thank you. What you suggested worked. But is it possible to edit `_command` function?

Comment: @Nikhil You can create and use your own function. Run `declare -f _command` and perform reverse engineering maybe. Good luck.